# Binding One Mesh to Another

Tags: workflow, shape-keys

I have 3 meshes: female feet, male feet (a shape key to female) and shoes.

When I morph the first mesh into the second, I need the third to follow. Binding shoes to female feet with Mesh deform is not an option since  the former are bigger than the later and are not being fully affected.

Is there a way of achieving it without scaling the shoes or feet?

Comment: I think the problem comes down to preparing two objects: feet (2 shape keys: male and female) and shoes (2 shape keys: male and female) and those shape keys have to match. Then right-click on the **value** of the second (not base) shape key of the feet, *"Copy as New Driver"*, go to the value of the second shape key of the shoes, right click, *"paste driver"*. Now all you have to do is to modify the 2nd shape key of the shoes so they fit well on the feet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a shrinkwrap modifier on the shoe? But to be honest this might be a slightly more complex setup.

Some others ideas:
Use a driver linking shapekey influence to a shapekey on the shoe.
Use shrinkwrap but with a simpler mesh, that in return influence the high res shoe through a mesh deform.

Got to see your file for more help.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to solidify some faces of the foot into a shoe and use shape keys to morph.